Relationship between gravitational force and fusion energy in stars
From what I understand, stars like our Sun constantly have a gravitational force on their surface due to their mass, which is balanced out by the fusion reactions taking place in the core of the Sun.
I am confused on how a force is balanced out by the energy from fusion. Like how do they interrelate. If I know some amount of Energy is being produced by fusion every second, is there a way I can convert that to force to see if it is equal to the gravitational force?

Related, possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/242808/123208

Does this answer your question? How to calculate the force of gravity that wants to collapse a star?

It is not quite the "gravitational force on [its] surface" that has to be balanced by the fusion energy, rather it is teh requirement that, at equilibrium, the gravitational forces on each element of volume in the sun are balanced by the local pressure within the same volume element.
To a first oprder approximation, you can consider the sun to be a big ball of a perfect gas, held together by its own gravity. Just like our own atmosphere, the local pressure increases as you descend into the sun due to the 'weight' of all the gas above it. To be in equilibrium, i.e. for any local volume at some depth r not to suddenly expand or collapse, the pressure within that local volume has to exactly balance the mass of gas above it.
In principle, a 'cold' perfect gas could be in equilibrium and it is fairly simple to calculate a classical approximation for P(r) using the idealised PVT gas laws and Newton's law of gravity. In practice though, a body of gas is likely to be warmer as you descend into it, as a result of internal fusion plus the gravitational energy released when the body of gas is initially assembled.
But, for any given internal heat source, there will be a pressure P(r), and a temperature T(r), that will result from a rate of fusion energy production W(r) and a rate that the energy can radiate/conduct/convect towards the surface (call it D(r)) allow for the fact that fusion energy generation wil be a very strong function of pressure, temperature, and relative density of teh various elements that make up the internal atmosphere etc, but I am sure you get the general picture.
The main point in terms of 'balance' is that if you hav ean appropriate T(r), P(r), W(r), and D(r) then everywhere in the sun will be in a local equilibrium and the inward forces (gravity) are balanced by the outward forces (local pressure). But now imagine that the rate of energy production W(r) drops within some region of the sun. The region is still radiating heat but no longer generating as much, thus itsinternal temperature will drop. So according to PV ~ T, if T drops a little then so will PV. Thus pressure of that region will initially reduce. As a result, it wil be compressed by teh weight of gas above it and V will reduce - pushing P (and T) back upwards as the gas within the region is compressed. If the reduction in W(r) is small then the sun may just contract a little, but in real stars things are a lot more chaotic - the reduction in V means an increase in density, so fusion rate may increase for example, which will push T up further. Complications ensue... Thus local 'imbalance' in the interior of a star can be sufficient to cause novas, supernovas and other startling events.

It's actually not much different than a diesel engine.  In the engine:

The mechanical force of the piston compresses a gas to a much smaller volume, and higher pressure and temperature
The high pressure and temperature cause the fuel mixed in with the gas to ignite and release energy
The released energy caused even higher temperature and pressure in the gas, which pushes back on the piston with mechanical force, making the engine run

Now the forces in a star operate essentially the same way, except frozen in a static fashion rather than repeating in a cycle:

Mechanical force of gravity (the weight of the star's material) compresses the gas at the core of the star, creating very high pressures and temperatures
Those high pressures and temperatures cause the fuel (the gas itself) to ignite into nuclear fusion and release energy
The released energy causes even higher pressures abnd temperatures, which push back against gravity and stabilize the star, while also heating it so that it radiates all the energy we see

In fact, one could say that a star is like the piston engine cycle, but extremely slow moving, and currently in the portion where the ignited gas is in the process of pushing back against the piston. In some stars, the energy from the fuel wins, and the star explodes and then fizzles out (supernova). In other stars, the piston (gravity) wins and packs the gas into a solid and very hot remainder, like forging a diamond (white dwarf).  Or the piston really wins and collapses the gas into a black hole.
